# Removing Arrow/Plus?minus Icon for a particular node in Extjs Tree Panel

Tags: css, extjs

I have a Tree Panel in Extjs and I need to remove the Arrow icon if useArrows:true, for a particular node and also I need to change the background color. I found in firebug that  "x-tree-elbow-img" is the class sencha is using to render that particular image. I don't have any idea of how to implement this for a particular node.

Comment: Could you maybe make use of the 'x-grid-tree-node-expanded' class applied when an item is expanded? the class, off the top of my head would be something like .x-grid-tree-node-expanded .x-tree-elbow-img{...}

Comment: @PedroReis Thanks! It worked.